# Java color changing Text with Timer. you can help pls?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, timer

I want to write text that changes colors twice a second. Can someone tell me why it doesn't work ? if you could explain to me how to do it I would be very happy.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder;

public class test {

    private JFrame frmTest;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JLabel lblNombreUtilisPour;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JLabel lblNombreChiffr;
    private JLabel lblNombreDechiffr;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JButton btnDehiffrer;
    private JSeparator separator;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextField textField_6;
    private JLabel label_2;
    private JTextField textField_7;
    private JLabel label_3;
    private JButton button_1;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                test window = new test();
                window.frmTest.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
public test() {


    initialize();


    }







/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
    private void initialize() {




        Random rand = new Random();
        float r = rand.nextFloat();
        float g = rand.nextFloat();
        float b = rand.nextFloat();

        Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);



        frmTest = new JFrame();

        frmTest.setResizable(false);
        frmTest.setTitle("TPE");
        frmTest.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 450);
        frmTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmTest.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("test5.gif"));

        label_1.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        frmTest.setContentPane(label_1);




        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setSelectedTextColor(randomColor.brighter());
        textField.setOpaque(false);
        textField.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        textField.setName("");
        textField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        textField.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                textField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
                    public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

                     if(!(Character.isDigit(evt.getKeyChar()))){
                            evt.consume();
                        }



                    }

                });

            }
        });
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textField.setToolTipText("Entrer un nombre ici");
        textField.setBounds(215, 32, 219, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        textField.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(9));

        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Entrer un nombre:");
        lblNewLabel.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 30, 141, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setSelectedTextColor(randomColor.brighter());
        textField_1.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        textField_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        textField_1.setOpaque(false);
        textField_1.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        textField_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textField_1.setToolTipText("Nombre utilisé pour chiffrer: ");
        textField_1.setEditable(false);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(215, 63, 219, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(textField_1);

        lblNombreUtilisPour = new JLabel("Nombre utilisé pour chiffrer: ");
        lblNombreUtilisPour.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        lblNombreUtilisPour.setToolTipText("Nombre utilisé pour chiffrer: ");
        lblNombreUtilisPour.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblNombreUtilisPour.setBounds(10, 61, 195, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(lblNombreUtilisPour);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setSelectedTextColor(randomColor.brighter());
        textField_2.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        textField_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        textField_2.setOpaque(false);
        textField_2.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        textField_2.setEditable(false);
        textField_2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textField_2.setToolTipText("Nombre chiffré: ");
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        textField_2.setBounds(215, 94, 219, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(textField_2);

        lblNombreChiffr = new JLabel("Nombre chiffré: ");
        lblNombreChiffr.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        lblNombreChiffr.setToolTipText("Nombre chiffré: ");
        lblNombreChiffr.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblNombreChiffr.setBounds(10, 92, 195, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(lblNombreChiffr);

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setSelectedTextColor(randomColor.brighter());
        textField_3.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        textField_3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        textField_3.setOpaque(false);
        textField_3.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        textField_3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textField_3.setEditable(false);
        textField_3.setToolTipText("Nombre dechiffré: ");
        textField_3.setColumns(10);
        textField_3.setBounds(215, 125, 219, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(textField_3);

        lblNombreDechiffr = new JLabel("Nombre dechiffré: ");
        lblNombreDechiffr.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        lblNombreDechiffr.setToolTipText("Nombre dechiffré: ");
        lblNombreDechiffr.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblNombreDechiffr.setBounds(10, 125, 151, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(lblNombreDechiffr);

        btnDehiffrer = new JButton("Dechiffrer");
        btnDehiffrer.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        btnDehiffrer.setBorder(null);
        btnDehiffrer.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnDehiffrer.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                int min = 0;
                int max = 250;

                Random r = new Random();

                //Demande de nombre 
                int nmb = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());

                //Chifrement

                int chif = r.nextInt(max-min) * r.nextInt(max-min) + r.nextInt(max-min) / r.nextInt(max-min);

                int chif_nmb = nmb * chif;
                int dechif_nmb = chif_nmb / chif;

                textField_3.setText(""+dechif_nmb);





            }
        });



        JButton btnButton1 = new JButton("Chiffrer");
        btnButton1.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        btnButton1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnButton1.setBorder(null);
        btnButton1.setOpaque(false);
        btnButton1.setToolTipText("Chiffrer");
        btnButton1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        btnButton1.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        btnButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                int min = 0;
                int max = 250;

                Random r = new Random();

                //Demande de nombre 
                int nmb = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());

                //Chifrement

                int chif = r.nextInt(max-min) * r.nextInt(max-min) + r.nextInt(max-min) / r.nextInt(max-min);

                textField_1.setText(""+chif);

                int chif_nmb = nmb * chif;

                textField_2.setText(""+chif_nmb);





            }
        });

        btnButton1.setBounds(0, 156, 450, 23);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(btnButton1);
        btnDehiffrer.setToolTipText("Dechiffrer");
        btnDehiffrer.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        btnDehiffrer.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        btnDehiffrer.setBounds(0, 190, 450, 23);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(btnDehiffrer);

        separator = new JSeparator();
        separator.setOpaque(true);
        separator.setBackground(randomColor.brighter());
        separator.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        separator.setBounds(0, 224, 450, 2);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(separator);

        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.setSelectedTextColor(randomColor.brighter());
        textField_4.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        textField_4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        textField_4.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        textField_4.setOpaque(false);
        textField_4.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                textField_4.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
                    public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

                     if(!(Character.isDigit(evt.getKeyChar()))){
                            evt.consume();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        textField_4.setToolTipText("Entrer un nombre ici");
        textField_4.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textField_4.setColumns(10);
        textField_4.setBounds(215, 261, 219, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(textField_4);
        textField_4.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(9));

        label = new JLabel("Entrer un nombre:");
        label.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        label.setBounds(10, 259, 141, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(label);

        textField_6 = new JTextField();
        textField_6.setSelectedTextColor(randomColor.brighter());
        textField_6.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        textField_6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        textField_6.setOpaque(false);
        textField_6.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        textField_6.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                textField_6.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
                    public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

                     if(!(Character.isDigit(evt.getKeyChar()))){
                            evt.consume();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        textField_6.setToolTipText("Nombre chiffré: ");
        textField_6.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textField_6.setColumns(10);
        textField_6.setBounds(215, 292, 219, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(textField_6);      
        textField_6.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(9));    





        label_2 = new JLabel("Nombre chiffré: ");
        label_2.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        label_2.setToolTipText("Nombre chiffré: ");
        label_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        label_2.setBounds(10, 290, 195, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(label_2);

        textField_7 = new JTextField();
        textField_7.setSelectedTextColor(randomColor.brighter());
        textField_7.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        textField_7.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        textField_7.setOpaque(false);
        textField_7.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        textField_7.setEditable(false);
        textField_7.setToolTipText("Nombre dechiffré: ");
        textField_7.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textField_7.setColumns(10);
        textField_7.setBounds(215, 323, 219, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(textField_7);

        label_3 = new JLabel("Nombre dechiffré: ");
        label_3.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        label_3.setToolTipText("Nombre dechiffré: ");
        label_3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        label_3.setBounds(10, 321, 151, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(label_3);





        button = new JButton("Chiffrer");
        button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setBorder(null);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                //Demande de nombre 
                int nmb = Integer.parseInt(textField_4.getText());



                //Chifrement

                int chif_nmb = (510-nmb)+834*nmb;

                textField_6.setText(""+chif_nmb);


            }
        });
        button.setToolTipText("Chiffrer");
        button.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        button.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        button.setBounds(0, 354, 450, 23);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(button);


        button_1 = new JButton("Dechiffrer");
        button_1.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        button_1.setBorder(null);
        button_1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                //Demande de nombre 


                int nmb = Integer.parseInt(textField_6.getText());

                //Chifrement

                int chif_nmb = (nmb - 510)/833;

                textField_7.setText(""+chif_nmb);


            }
        });
        button_1.setToolTipText("Dechiffrer");
        button_1.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        button_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        button_1.setBounds(0, 388, 450, 23);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(button_1);

        JLabel lblCh = new JLabel("Chiffrement complexe");
        lblCh.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        lblCh.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 19));
        lblCh.setBounds(121, 0, 219, 28);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(lblCh);

        JLabel label_4 = new JLabel("Chiffrement normal");
        label_4.setForeground(randomColor.brighter());
        label_4.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 19));
        label_4.setBounds(121, 230, 219, 28);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(label_4);








    }





}
```

Comment: `I want to write text that changes colors twice a second.` - so then create an [mcve] that only does this. That is all you need is a frame with a component and the text changes when the Timer fires. All the other code you posted is irrelevant to your stated question and we don't have the time to find the code only related to your specific problem. `it's really very urgent.` - also irrelevant. People answer questions when the have time and think they know the answer. I suggest you get rid of those comments.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem description. And that sure is a lot of code for an attempt at changing text color.

Comment: *"Can someone tell me why it doesn't work ?"* Well the text 'timer' does not appear anywhere in the 466 lines of code presented above. You might start looking there. If that tip does not help solve the problem, follow the advice of @camickr.

Comment: BTW 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Thread changing the color of your component as needed, eg :

```
class Effect extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                yourLabel.setForeground(new Color(aValue, bValue, cValue)); // you can apply coloring logic
                Thread.sleep(500); //sleep for 0.5 secs , so your color changes twice every second
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GUI updates should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread. A `javax.swing.Timer` (that operates on the EDT) makes this easy.

Comment: @Andrew agreed - but as an alternative couldn't the above thread (eg converted to Runnable) to be invoked from the EDT ?

Comment: Action could be taken to put the call to change the label color on the EDT, but using a Swing `Timer` is easier.

Comment: can you tell me where I should place it? please

Comment: @Mozart my suggestion is not using Timer, if you want to use it you could create this Thread as a nested class in your code and start it with something like `new Effect().start()`